# Array of points algorithm

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I'm having trouble designing an algorithm that will pretty much make a line move like in a snake game using an array that holds all the points on the line. I would do something like...

```
for (int x = 0; i < array.length; i++) { 
     array[i] = array[i+1]
}
array[array.length] = (the new point)
```

but this will happen many times a second and it is very slow. I thought of doing something similar but instead of moving each number every time, they stay in the same position in the array but an int is saved to keep track of which one will be removed next and which will contain the new nummber.
If you have any idea what I just said, please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [circular buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer). This can be implemented using an array and two indices (one for head, one for tail). If the snake always has the same length, you can get away with using a single index.

With such a structure, the entire operation that you require can be done in constant time (i.e. independent of the size of the array).

Answer (score 1):

You're correct to think that moving all of the blocks each time is slow.

There is a more efficient way to do it.

Only the first at last positions change with each move.

So, if you have your snake `array[i]` and a "head" marker `head` then you can simply march `head` through your array and overwrite the next location with where the head moved that turn.

The place you just overwrote?  That was where the tail was, and you don't need it anymore.

It gets a little trickier if the snake grows, but not too much more so.

(The data structure, as NPE points out, is a circular buffer.)

Answer (score 0):

```
int front, back, length; // 0<=front,back<length

increaseLength()
{
   back--;
   if(back<0)
      back=length-1;
}

goForward()
{
   front++;
   back++;
   if (front==length)
      front=0;

   if (back==length)
      back=0;
}

checkFull() // check every time you increase length
{
   if (back==front)
      return true;
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

NPE is correct that a circular buffer is the best solution.  This is a simple example of a circular buffer using C++.  Notice the modulus operators instead of `if` tests.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int front = 4;
    int back = 0;
    int length = 10;
    int snake[10] = { 1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0 };

    for (int i = 0; i < length * 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)
            std::cout << snake[j] << " ";
        std::cout << std::endl;

        snake[back] = 0;
        front = (front + 1) % length;
        back = (back + 1) % length;
        snake[front] = 1;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1
1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1
1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1
1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1
1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1
1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

Notice how the output nicely demonstrates the snake "moving" through the buffer.